# How to match row and cells between 2 Arraylist integer

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have two arraylist. The first arraylist a1, containing the number of row, and the second arraylist a2, containing the number of cell like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do here is I'm trying to set the color based on the number of row and cells that I store inside the a1 and a2 based on the location of X which the value of row and cells has been stored inside the a1 and a2 like this:

```
  a1: contain the current no of row that x located

  a2: contain the current no of cell that x located
```

I have tried this:

```
for (int v3 : a1) {
            for (int p3 : a2) {
                XSSFRow BOFF = sheet.getRow(v3);
                if (BOFF.getCell(p3) != null) {
                    BOFF.getCell(p3).setCellStyle(offcolor);
                } else {
                    Cell cell1 = BOFF.createCell(p3);
                    cell1.setCellStyle(offcolor);
                }
            }
        }
```

But the result is not correct which same as in the red highlighted cells inside the image above. I tried to switch between a1 and a2 but the result will also be the same. Anyone has idea how to do this so it will color on the X correctly?

**UPDATE:**

here I provide how i add the data into arraylist:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> a1= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> a2= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

here is how I search for the row and cell

```
for (int i = 0; i < mainArrayList.size(); i++) {
ArrayList<String> row = mainArrayList.get(i);
for (int t = 0; t < row.size(); t++) {

    if (row.get(t).equals("X")) {

        a1.add(i);
        a2.add(t);
        continue;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When I run my the code, it result like this:

[image]

Comment: why `a1` correspond to row index in your image, but when you loop, `a1` is used as column index?

Comment: @samabcde I just realized my mistake there. change it but the result still the same

Comment: Since `a1` and `a2` are of size 8, you are looping 64 times now. It should only loop 8 times as there is only 8 'x' . I suspect that you should now see row 1,2,5-8 of column 0 and 2 should be red color now.

Comment: @samabcde yes. see my latest update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

As in the example given, `a1` and `a2` has 8 element, hence the code looping logic in the given code is

> For **each** row having 'x' loop for **each** column having 'x', set the background color

Hence the background color of row 1,2,5-8 of column 0 and 2 are set.

### Solution

For a quick fix, just change the code to loop each pair of element in `a1` and `a2`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
    int rowIndex = a1.get(i);
    int colIndex = a2.get(i);
    XSSFRow BOFF = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    if (BOFF.getCell(colIndex) != null) {
        BOFF.getCell(colIndex).setCellStyle(offcolor);
    } else {
        Cell cell1 = BOFF.createCell(colIndex);
        cell1.setCellStyle(offcolor);
    }
}
```

However, using two array to store coordinates is not good, as `a1` and `a2` may have different length(due to program error), and leading unexpected behavior which is difficult to debug.

To address this, we can use [CellAddress](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellAddress.html) class of POI and refactor the code as

```
for (CellAddress xCellAddress : xCellAddresses) {
    XSSFRow BOFF = sheet.getRow(xCellAddress.getRow());
    if (BOFF.getCell(xCellAddress.getColumn()) != null) {
        BOFF.getCell(xCellAddress.getColumn()).setCellStyle(offcolor);
    } else {
        Cell cell1 = BOFF.createCell(xCellAddress.getColumn());
        cell1.setCellStyle(offcolor);
    }
}
```

Which is more readable and easier to debug.

Comment: thank you so much. thanks for the suggestion. I will check the CellAddress :)